# prevent UIScrollView to send touches to subview

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

How can I prevent the UIScrollView to send touches to it's subviews?

Comment: I don't think the title says it all...could you (sugar coated) please elaborate a little... as in do u want your subview to stay still while u scroll the UIScrollView?

Comment: Well, my subview draws stuff on the screen. Sometimes when I am scrolling / zooming in, the touch methods in get invoked and it starts drawing even though i just intended to zoom/pan around. So when I am zooming/panning around, i want the subviews to not receive any touch events so they dont draw stuff.

Comment: are the touches required for scrolling/zooming totally different from the touch required for drawing stuff? They most probably are...so you just need to differentiate(by using a boolean) and accordingly not draw stuff when you detect scrolling/zooming

Answer (score -1):

your `subview.userInteractionEnabled = NO;`

Answer (score -1):

Inherit from UIScrollView and define your own hitTest in following way:

```
@implementation MyScrollView

- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {  
    return [self pointInside:point withEvent:event] ? self : nil;     
}

@end
```

So, touches will not be forwarded into internal subviews and will stay on a level of UIScrollView.